# Simple QlikView Mashup (iframe embed) - why does it work with anonymous?

Tags: html, qlikview

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview-developer/November2017/Subsystems/Mashups/Content/mashups-start.htm

The above article discusses ways in which we can embed QlikView components (via iframes) in our own external website.

I've proven this with a document I have, and it works. But why does it work without me having to authenticate/login? If I log out of qlikview (in a different tab) and refresh my page that has the iframe on it still renders the contents.

If it's by design that users anonymous (to the QlikView system) can view content, what is the purpose of licensing? I was under the impression you needed a license to view the content - but now anybody viewing my web page can view QlikView charts?

Comment: Loggong out does not work. Go to the web page again. Enter developer tools and delete all the cookies, cache, session params. Then try again

Comment: Ah thanks @EldadT. I suppose the next question then is how I could embed the qlikview charts on my web page on various machines to people not logged in (It's a monitor/dashboard of sorts). Or, since it seems that's not possible,what might be the best approach to sharing the account and logging in as part of my system (if that's not a breach of any of the licensing terms)? Thanks for the rwply